# Javascript: Chrome Dev.Tools или NetBeans?

Tags: maven, google-chrome, tomcat, netbeans, веб-программирование

Когда я разворачиаваю java web application на контейнере tomcat с помощью мавена, я не знаю как мне писать JS в реалтайме (сохранил-посмотрел на изменения) без переустановки приложения. Если я пишу JS в chrome dev tools, то я должен каждый раз переустанавливать application.

В NB проще, при сохранении файлов он перекидывает изменённые файлы в ту папку, откуда их берёт сервер приложений. Я бы мог писать JS в netbeans полностью и забыть про chrome dev tools, но у хрома есть JS консоль (которую в NB я не нашел).

Не использовать же мне html проекты - времянки, а потом перекидывать готовые js файлы в свой основной проект. Я использую jsp+spring mvc. И мне надо видеть изменения, которые я вношу.

Что делать? Как разрабатывают и отлаживают JS в таких случаях?

Answer (score 2):

В NetBeans 8 реализована поддержка HTML5 проектов, в том числе встроенный веб-сервер, работающий "из коробки", и тот же NetBeans Connector для хрома и других браузеров, который позволяет делать интерактивную отладку, а также немедленно применять изменения, в т.ч. из отладчика Хрома - обратно в Нетбинс. Очень удобно, как по мне, постоянно пользуюсь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не подходит мне. Т.к. я использую java web app, которое каждый раз надо переустанавливать. Побродя, нашёл http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143453/best-way-of-javascript-web-development-in-netbeans-hot-deployment , где советуют разделить статические страницы в апач-сервер и дебажить их так. В итоге я решил юзать Мозиллу+firebug для отладки (благо там есть консоль в firebug).